# Error while executing Dataflow template using cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

Getting below error while trying to execute custom dataflow template using Google Cloud function.

Error:"problem running dataflow template, error was: { Error: A Forbidden error was returned while attempting to retrieve an access token for the Compute Engine built-in service account. This may be because the Compute Engine instance does not have the correct permission scopes specified. Could not refresh access token".

I have tried supplying all the required permissions and scopes.Could someone please suggest a resolution.

Answer (score 4):

The [google-cloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node) node library does not yet support the Dataflow API, so the current way to use that API is the [googleapis](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) library.

Following the instructions there, I've tried to launch a Dataflow job with a [Google-provided](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#bulk-decompress-cloud-storage-files) template using an HTTP-triggered function, and had no issues:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const project = "your-project-id"

exports.launchDataflowTemplate = (req, res) => {
    let result;
    google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function(err, authClient, projectId) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
                authClient = authClient.createScoped([
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute',
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly',
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
                ]);
            }
            var dataflow = google.dataflow({
                version: "v1b3",
                auth: authClient
            });

            var launchParams = {
                "inputFilePattern": "gs://your-input-bucket/*.gz",
                "outputDirectory": "gs://your-result-bucket/",
                "outputFailureFile": "gs://your-logs-bucket/error.csv"
            };

            var env = {
               "tempLocation": "gs://your-staging-bucket/temp",
               "zone": "us-central1-f"
            }


            var opts = {
                projectId: project,
                gcsPath: "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Bulk_Decompress_GCS_Files",
                resource: {
                    parameters: launchParams,
                    environment: env
                }
            };

            dataflow.projects.templates.launch(opts, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                res.send(result.data);
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi @Jofre, I'm trying your code but fails with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApplicationDefault' of undefined". Which Node an googleapis versions did you use?

Comment: Are you running this inside GCF? It looks like an issue with the library gathering the credentials.

Comment: It works with `{"dependencies":{"googleapis" : "22.2.0"}}` but fails with `{"dependencies":{"googleapis" : "28.1.0"}}`. Looks related to [this comment](https://shinesolutions.com/2017/03/23/triggering-dataflow-pipelines-with-cloud-functions/#comment-40947) on a related post. I'll look a little further.

Comment: yeah, it looks they made some changes to the module. Changing the require to `const { google } = require('googleapis');` fixed it

Comment: Written as is, version `24.0.0` is the last to work, and `25.0.0` fails. I'll try your suggestion later and update the answer accordingly. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: @garcianavalon Your fix works with newer versions, so I've updated the answer. Many thanks!

Comment: can anyone summarise the difference between `dataflow.projects.templates.launch` and `dataflow.projects.templates.create`

Comment: Could someone clarify where the `res` variable is coming from? I'm trying to do something very similar to whats in the answer, except I'm triggering on cloud storage.objects.finalize rather than HTTP trigger. I've got all the logic, except for the actual sending of the request - here it seems that `res.send(result.data);` does that, I don't know what my equivalent would be because I don't have that variable `res`. (I'm new to JS, coming from python)

Comment: Typing out the question was actually all I needed to answer it - res is just a callback to send back the result of the dataflow execution request. I can just log it to the console. :)